# Exercise 12 in Tao's notes on the semi-circular law

Tags: probability-theory, random-matrices

My question concerns [this exercise](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/254a-notes-4-the-semi-circular-law/#direct) in Tao's notes on the semi-circular law for random matrices. We are trying to solve equation (22) in the notes, which is a quadratic equation whose coefficients are given up to $o(1)$ accuracy:

$$\displaystyle  {\bf E} s_n(z) = - \frac{1}{z + {\bf E} s_n(z)} + o(1). \ \ \ \ \ $$

Here the $s_n$ are the Stieltjes transforms of a sequence of measures, and we would like to obtain
$$\displaystyle  {\bf E}s_n(z)=\frac{-z + \sqrt{z^2-4}}{2} + o(1)\ \ \ \ \ $$

Tao mentions we can do this using a "robust version of the quadratic formula." What does he mean by this?

It's tempting for me to just say that the roots of a quadratic are continuous functions of the coefficients, and so the given statement is obvious. Is it really that easy?

Comment: Please make your question reasonably self-contained, so that people don't have to follow the link to know what you're talking about. That said, "robust" here might mean "numerically robust/stable".

Comment: @user21820 Right, one is going to need something that behaves well when  the coefficients vary a little. I'm just not sure what that is, exactly.

Comment: What is $o(1)$ with respect to? As what goes to what? I don't feel like wading through the whole post to figure out, so if you could really make your question self-contained it would be better. I'm guessing that the usual formula does not work because the $o(1)$ term is amplified by multiplying the equation by $f(z)+z$, but I'm 100% sure there is no need for any 'robust quadratic formula' in the first place.

Comment: @user21820 The $o(1)$ is with respect to $n$. Why are you sure there is no need for a "robust quadratic formula"? It seems we can just use continuity of the roots to get the desired result, but maybe Tao is suggesting we can get a quantitative bound on the rate of convergence.

Comment: I'm sure because we can simply use a constant in place of that $o(1)$ term, solve the quadratic, and then analyze its asymptotic behaviour. Are you sure the $o(1)$ does not depend on $z$? If so, we need uniform convergence over all $z$. If not, then you need to specify what is $z$.

Comment: @user21820 Here $z$ is fixed throughout, and the equation we want to obtain also has $z$ fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $z,c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = -\frac1{f(z)+z} + c$:

$f(z)^2 + z f(z) + 1 = c (f(z)+z)$.

$4f(z)^2 + 4(z-c) f(z) + 4(1-cz) = 0$.

$( 2f(z) + z-c )^2 = (z-c)^2 - 4 + 4cz = z^2 - 4 + 2cz + c^2$.

Note that (using principal branch for $\sqrt{}$):
$\def\wi{\subseteq}$

$\sqrt{a+o(1)} \wi \sqrt{a} \sqrt{1+o(1)} \wi \sqrt{a}(1+o(1)) \wi \sqrt{a}+o(1)$ for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

As $n \to \infty$, and given $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = -\frac1{f(z)+z} + o(1)$:

$( 2f(z) + z-o(1) )^2 \wi z^2 - 4 + o(1)$.

Thus $2f(z) + z-o(1) \wi \sqrt{z^2-4} + o(1)$.

Thus $f(z) \in \dfrac{-z+\sqrt{z^2-4}}{2} + o(1)$.

Note that if you want more precise error bounds, you will have to use the Taylor expansion for $\sqrt{}$, in which case you have to distinguish two cases:

1. If $z^2-4$ is bounded away from $0$, then the error term is of the same order.
2. If not, then the error term can be up to the square-root of the original.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it is correct that what you want follows from continuity of the (complex) roots with respect to the coefficients of a quadratic equation, but then you need to prove that first, which amounts to the same thing as what I did.